# Control height of datatableoutput in rstudio viewer

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

Consider the following markdown document:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        mtcars,
        server = FALSE,
        selection = list(mode = "multiple", target = "column", selected = c(1)),
        options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE)
    )
}

runApp(
    appDir = shinyApp(ui, server), 
    launch.browser = rstudioapi::viewer
)
```
````

If i run the shiny app from rmarkdown, the table is not fully shown. If i click on "open in browser", everything is rendered fine.

**Question:**

How can i Show the table on the full page within the Viewer if i invoke the app from rmarkdown?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest method would be to add `height` to `dataTableOutput`. You can play around with the number, and also try "rem", "px", etc. – "em" worked best for me. You might also want to try adding the `width` argument so the table scales when you resize the window, and perhaps try removing `autoWidth` from `options`, depending on how the final product looks.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl", height = "40em")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        mtcars,
        server = FALSE,
        selection = list(mode = "multiple", target = "column", selected = c(1)),
        options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE)
    )
}

runApp(
    appDir = shinyApp(ui, server), 
    launch.browser = rstudioapi::viewer
)
```
````

[image: Screenshot of datatable]

Comment: hah, i tried height = 100%, but that didnt work. I actually thought i tried the alternatives. Thx! Its beyond the scope of my quesetion, but do you know if there is a possibility to scale the height to the Viewer pane height?

Comment: @Tlatwork I'm afraid not. You would need some way to either subdivide the table height by the number or rows, i.e. the rows expand as the table expands, or more rows should appear as the containing table expands. Either way, it's a bit more complex than just setting the table height to some absolute or relative dimension. I'm sure there's a way to set the row heights, although it might not be immediately obvious. Perhaps via some custom CSS?

Comment: i just found that `rstudioapi::viewer(..., height = 300)` takes a height argument. So there might be at least an approximate solution to scale the table according to Viewer pane. Interestingly enough, for me, using the height Argument only works if the Parameter increases the current height of the pane. Not if its lower,...

Comment: hmm but not sure one can use it with `runApp(,...launch.browser = rstudioapi::viewer,...)` together,...